# Проблемы с кодировкой при выводе из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, сменил хостинг с sprinthost на majordomo и связался с проблемой в кодировке при выводе из базы...
В БД поставил как стояло в прошлой БД - utf8_unicod_ci.
Вот сама ошибка
**`Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u*****/********/www/connectdb.php on line 9`**

PDO не использую.
Вот моё подключение к бд

При выводе использую:

```
<?php 
$users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$user = mysql_fetch_array($users);
?>
```

Comment: Вам сообщают о том, что mysql пользоваться не надо, а надо mysqli или pdo

Comment: Хорошо, как начать использовать mysqli?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php Это связно не с хостером, а с версией php. Mysql в 7 версии уже отсутствует совсем

Comment: Ах вот оно что....

Comment: @splash58 то есть мне достаточно сменить версию php?

Comment: Я советую вам перейти - это более безопасно. Но если уж очень хотите, то можете или версию понизить, или просто забить - работать все равно будет

Comment: На старом хостинге стоит 5.6 версия, на этом 5.5...
Точно в этом косяк?

Comment: Разный уровень сообщений об ошибках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНО
Вставил в connectdb.php строчку после подключения `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` - избавило от хреновой кодировки
+ сменил версию PHP на 5.4 - избавило от ошибки

Comment: Да, и смени версию PHP на 7.1.1